# Is there a way to display some web-page on separate monitor constantly, even if computer is locked?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I would like to display web-page with some real-time status information constantly. If I just configure two monitors and open fill-screen web-browser with this web-page on one of monitors, then web-page is not shown when computer is locked.

Is there any software for Windows 7 which allows constant displaying some custom information on separate monitor?

Comment: Locking the computer will disable the screen, by design. There's *no* way to bypass that.

Comment: Actually, I wonder, is there any software, which allows to treat additional monitor not as extension of user workspace (as done by default), but as a separate device which can show some abstract picture.

Comment: Possibly, or even as a screen saver. But as soon as you lock the computer, it is unavailable until a password is typed in. That's the entire point.